# Hazelcast wan replication and map entry listener

Tags: hazelcast

I'm trying to implement wan-replication with hazelcast (3.8 or later). In passive cluster, there is no entry event fired (entryAdded, entryUpdated...).

How can I catch those events in passive cluster???

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Entry listeners are fired when operations are submitted directly to the IMap. But you can take a look at http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.2/manual/html-single/index.html#event-filtering-api and implement the Event Filter to catch and process WAN events.